# How to make a program check a picture box intersects with another control?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I was wondering how I could check if a picturebox intersects with another thing on the form. I know for a rectangle its:

```
if (rectangle.IntersectsWith(otherRectangle))
```

but (i know, not possible) i want to do like the above:

```
if (pictureBox1.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2))
```

Anyone know a good way to check? Also, im making a game in which you can move the picture box 1 with arrows keys, and jump with space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two controls are children of the same form or container, then you can check whether the controls overlap by getting their [`Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and calling `IntersectsWith`:

```
if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds))
```

[`DisplayRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the wrong property to access; for a PictureBox, it returns (0, 0, Width, Height), so `IntersectsWith` will always return true if Width and Height are nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

If two picture boxes are within the same parent then:

```
pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.DisplayRectangle)
```