# Check bounds of a list of images (or the one currently being used in the list)

Tags: c#

I have a cat and mouse game and I have the mouse randomly moving about with timers and direction change etc. When the mouse moves left, the picture box changes to another completely separate file so it looks like it has turned.

I'm now trying to check if the cat has collided with the mouse so that I can end the game.

Does anyone know how I could check the current bounds of the mouse so I can detect when its been hit? I can provide any code needed but as it is long I'll copy and paste on request.

that the question linked below was how i was planning on doing it,

```
public void Collsions()
         {
           if (Cat.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Mouse.bounds))
         }
```

but i then realized that the MouseBounds cant fine a bound as the image changes all the time depending on its direction

```
MouseImage.Image = MouseImages.Images[(int)currentDirection];
```

so there is a list of images that change depending on the direction of the mouse,and i don't know how to check the bounds after the image is changed.

this is all the mouse code:
https://pastebin.com/aEUWBdru

this is all the cat code (so far);
https://pastebin.com/ndAbDv5c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a program check a picture box intersects with another control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746282/how-to-make-a-program-check-a-picture-box-intersects-with-another-control) Code in the answers here show how to tell if two pictureboxes intersect eachother, which I think is, ultimately, what you are looking for. Instead of dealing with bounds and all that.

Comment: We know how the world moves around the sun because books have told us properly about it.We will know what you are asking for once you tell us how you coded your game :)